# Facebook Graph API : Getting posts from pages with country / age restriction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get posts from a page that uses country / age restriction using Graph API, but I'm always getting this error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '105590939487217' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "GSuXXzncAOX"
  }
}
```

Is there anyone who solved this problem before ?

Comment: Because your access token are not allowed to see it. You need to use a page access token for that page. Or you need to use a user access token that pass the restrictions on the page

Comment: I'm able to access the page from the browser using a VPN. But when I try that with the Graph API explorer tool, i'm getting the same error message. PS : I've used a page access token but it doesnt work

Comment: That you can see it in the browser doesn't matter. Is it a page access token for that specific page?

Comment: No. I don't have the access to that page :(

Comment: Then that is the reason. Then you would need to use a user access token that can see the page

Comment: I have already tried to use a user access token that see the page but it doesn't work :(

Comment: It works if the user access token can see the objects

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I've discovered that I need to create a Facebook account using using an IP address of one of the page supported countries. It seems that Facebook detects the user country based on other criterias than the IP address.